# Gulp not injecting jquery ui theme css

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, gulp, bower

Im using [this](https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular) to generate a gulp application. I have added jquery ui in my bower.json but for some odd reason the jquery ui theme css is not automatically injected. The JS file is injected though. Here is what my bower.json looks like:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular-cookies": "~1.3.16",
    "angular-sanitize": "~1.3.16",
    "jquery": "~2.1.4",
    "jquery-ui": "1.11.4",
    "angular-resource": "~1.3.16",
    "angular-i18n": "1.4.4",
    "bootstrap-sass-official": "~3.3.4",
    "angular-bootstrap": "~0.13.0",
    "malarkey": "yuanqing/malarkey#~1.3.0",
    "toastr": "~2.1.1",
    "moment": "~2.10.3",
    "animate.css": "~3.3.0",
    "angular": "~1.3.16",
      "angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker": "0.3.13",
    "ag-grid": "1.12.4",
    "nya-bootstrap-select": "~2.0.10",
    "angular-messages": "~1.3.16",
       "angular-ui-router":"0.2.15",
    "angular-translate": "2.7.2",
    "angular-translate-loader-url": "2.7.2",
    "angular-translate-loader-static-files" : "2.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "~1.3.16"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "jquery": "~2.1.4",
    "angular": "~1.3.16"
  }
}
```

Anyone know what I'm missing?

Comment: What does your gulp file look like? You need to add a line in the gulp file to select the theme css

Answer (score 2):

following configuration to bower.json worked for me:

```
"overrides": {
  "jquery-ui": {
    "main": [
      "jquery-ui.js",
      "themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css"
    ]
  }
 }
```

This may help someone.

Best regards,

Comment: Yes this was necessary for me otherwise main-bower-files wouldn't include the CSS files.

Comment: Btw I think it's necessary for path to be  "themes/smoothness/**/*" to include the images in the build.